# Java Configuration of Spring Boot ApplicationPidListener

Tags: spring-boot

I read in the Spring Boot reference guide here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-process-monitoring

that an ApplicationPidListener can be programmatically set on a Spring Boot app.  This is great, but of course I would like a little more.

When I set the ApplicationPidListener per the Reference guide like this

```
app.addListeners(new ApplicationPidListener(pidFileName));
```

followed by starting the app like this

```
app.run(arguments.toArray(new String[arguments.size()]))
```

whereupon I obseved that any command line overrides of properties are not available that might have been used to instantiate the ApplicationPidListener pid file location.  Of course, I could parse the command line arguments myself, looking for a property that should be used to instantiate the ApplicationPidListener, but I would rather not do that.

My problem could perhaps be solved if I could provide the ApplicationPidListener as a Bean in a Java Configuration like this

```
    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public ApplicationListener pidListener(@Value("${pidFile:app.pid}") String prop) {
            return new ApplicationPidListener(prop);
        }
    }
```

and provide this Configuration to the constructor of the SpringApplication via configurationSources.toArray()

```
new SpringApplication(null, configurationSources.toArray())
```

In this way, the ApplicationPidListener would have full visibility into the Spring Boot-resolved properties, including command line overrides.  However, even though this Config leads to the Bean being created, of course, it is apparently not used by the application context to create the PID file.

My question is am I programmatically constrained to adding the listener before I call run, which means I have to look into the command line arguments to see if there is a pid file override there?

Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you simply merging the commandline arguments and whatever your `configurationsources` contain? What are those `configurationSources` anyway? Why do you need something else that isn't doable with the default Spring Boot configuration support?

Comment: This is a template-like application that has a builder layer on top of configuring SpringApplication and calling SpringApplication.run().  The builder layer exists to shield new microservice developers from having to know Spring Boot configuration in great detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I programmatically constrained to adding the listener before I call run?

Yes, you are. At the moment `ApplicationPidListener` writes the PID out in response to an `ApplicationStartedEvent`. This event is published very early in the lifecycle of an application. From the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationStartedEvent.html):

> Event published as early as conceivably possible as soon as a `SpringApplication` has been started - before the `Environment` or `ApplicationContext` is available, but after the `ApplicationListener`s have been registered

This prevents `ApplicationPidListener` from being configured as a Spring bean. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1579) that discusses making the location of the pid file configurable. The current proposal is to make the event that is listened for configurable and to use the `Environment` (e.g. an entry in `application.properties` or `application.yaml`), when it's available, to provide the location.